# Ubuntu version 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: asus, versions

I'm new here and I don't know which ubuntu version is better for my netbook ASUS Eee PC 1015PX. The 32 or 64 bit version.

Procesor specs can be found [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/55637/Intel-Atom-Processor-N570-1M-Cache-1_66-GHz)

Thanks!

Comment: Questions like this get closed for being "primarily opinion-based". Ubuntu and all its flavors are free. Have a look at the minumum specs for each flavor (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). Download and burn a couple of them that match your specs and see for yourself what works best for you.

Comment: Use the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
(32 bit or 64 bit) according to your system. As you are new read"The Linux Command Line
Second Internet Edition
William E. Shotts, Jr." and manual for the Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rinzwind! I think my question was not understanded well, not the flavor i'm intrested, but the specs of the procesor is confusing me. Im not sure if is built for 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend Ubuntu MATE 14.04 LTS because a dual-core laptop may be laggy with the normal Ubuntu flavour. However you can try the normal ubuntu, and if laggy, then try this.

[image: Ubuntu MATE Screenshot]
Download it [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/)

Comment: Many people thrills when looks this awful interface, but you can have a Firefox window **full** of tabs and it doesn't hangs in a dual core processor. However, if your computer supports the normal ubuntu flavour is better.

Comment: Ubuntu mate "webpage is not available" so i-ll try the normal one. Can you tell me if the 64 bit version fits for me? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have a 64 bit processor.

Comment: You're welcome! If do you have any doubt in the ubuntu installation or once installed, please ask here! If do you want more opinions, do not accept the question.